# Value "null" by default in String

Tags: java, string, null

I have this class

```
public class Model {    
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public synchronized String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public synchronized void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public synchronized String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public synchronized void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }   
}
```

I try to get the value of `a`, and I know that by [default](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) this variable is initialize to `null`. But, is it possible that if I call the `getA()` method, afterwards this variable has the String `"null"` on it (not `null` but the `String`)? So `a.equals("null") == true`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {      
Model m = new Model();
String test = m.getA();
m.getA().equals("null");//No Exception occurs
```

}

And in fact the code where I eval the String is part of an Android Application:

```
    mAirline = (Airline) extras.getSerializable("airline");     
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String test = mAirline.getPhone(); //(1)
    String test2 = mAirline.getHref(); //(2)
```

If I check mAirline in (1) mAirline has it fields in null, but in (2) has some of them to "null" And my method for get is

```
    public synchronized String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking, and the code snippet as you posted doesn't even compile since `a` is not defined. If you haven't explicitly set the value of `m.a`, it won't change by itself.

Comment: Sorry about it, hope now is clearer.

Comment: Aside from answers you you wold want to rewrite m.getA().equals("null") to "null".equals(m.getA()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, with the code you showed us, it's not possible that you automatically get the `String` `"null"`.

Note, however, that some methods **will** convert `null` to `"null"`. The most notable examples are [`PrintWriter.println()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) (as in [`System.out.println()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)) and [`String.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
System.out.println(null);
System.out.println("null".equals(String.valueOf(null)));
```

These line will print `null` (i.e. the 4 characters) and `true` respectively

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just:

```
private String a = "null";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check if the string is not null?

```
Model m = new Model();
String test = m.getA();
if(test==null) {
  //is null
} else {
  //is not null
}
```

You can also alter the getter method, so it returns your default value if the field is not initialized:

```
public class Model {    
    private String a;

    public synchronized String getA() {
        //if a is null, return "null", else return a
        return a==null?"null":a;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `String.valueOf()` returns `"null"` if the argument is `null` or the argument itself if it is a String that is different from `null`.

```
    Model m = new Model();
    String test = m.getA();
    if (String.valueOf(a).equals("null")) //No Exception occurs
```

but this is kind of cryptic, pretty hard to understand what you want to do.
Check for `null` directly, much easier to read:

```
    Model m = new Model();
    String test = m.getA();
    if (a == null || a.equals("null")) //No Exception occurs
```

Answer (score 0):

So you mean, the value of `a` is the string `null`, rather than a pointer with value null? That well never happen, unless you set it like that using `setA("null");`.

If you want `a` to be initialized as null, write a constructor:

```
public Model() {
    a = "null";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the problem for you. If the variable is null you will return "null" and if not you will return the value.

```
public class Model {    
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public synchronized String getA() {
        return (if (a ==null) ? "null" : a);
    }
    public synchronized void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public synchronized String getB() {
        return (if (b ==null) ? "null" : b);
    }
    public synchronized void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }   
}
```